# Why does Margin Collapsing only apply to top and bottom but not left and right

Tags: css

In CSS, what is the motivation for [margin-collapsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing) behavior only applying between top and bottom margins but not left and right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only block level elements can have their margin collapsed and if they are block level elements, they cannot have elements to their left or right.

See the following link for more information: [Why horizontal margin doesn't collapse as vertical margin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32838027/why-horizontal-margin-doesnt-collapse-as-vertical-margin)

Hope this helps.